# Filter search get an error message of req is not defined

Tags: node.js, express

I have created a multiple drop down menu so users can filter search by city, bedrooms, and bathrooms. The form will return all data that apply to the user's search. The search function, bedroomSearch function, and bathroomSearch function will handle all the search filtering. For some odd reason I keeping getting an error message saying  "ReferenceError: req is not defined". How do I get my filter to work?

form.ejs

```
<form action="/homes" method="GET" class="filter-form">

    <select name="search" id="form-city">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Search by City</option>
      <option value="New York">New York</option>
  <option value="CA">California</option>
  <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
  <option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
</select>

<select name="bed">
    <option value="3 Beds">3 Beds</option>
  <option value="5 Beds">5 Beds</option>
  <option value="6 Beds">6 Beds</option>
  <option value="8 Beds">8 Beds</option>

</select>

<select name="bath">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Bathrooms</option>
      <option value="New York">New York</option>
  <option value=" 3.5 baths"> 3.5 baths</option>
  <option value="5 baths"> 5 baths</option>
  <option value="6 baths"> 6 baths</option>
</select>


              <input type="submit" value="SEARCH" class="site-btn fs-submit">
          </form>
```

house.js

```
router.get("/", function(req, res){
  //function to search by city
  search();

  //function to search by bedrooms
  bedroomSearch();

  //function to search by bathrooms
  bathroomSearch()
});

//search functions
function citySearch() {
  var noMatch = null;
    if(req.query.search) {
        const regex = new RegExp(escapeRegex(req.query.search), 'gi');
        // Get all homes from DB
        Home.find({city: regex}, function(err, allHomes){
           if(err){
               console.log(err);
           } else {
              if(allHomes.length < 1) {
                  noMatch = "No homes match that query, please try again.";
              }
              res.render("homes/index",{homes:allHomes, noMatch: noMatch});
           }
        });
    } else {
        // Get all homes from DB
        Home.find({}, function(err, allHomes){
           if(err){
               console.log(err);
           } else {
              res.render("homes/index",{homes:allHomes, noMatch: noMatch});
           }
        });
    }

}
// end of city search function

function bedroomSearch() {
  var noMatch = null;
    if(req.query.bed) {
        const regexBed = new RegExp(escapeRegex(req.query.bed), 'gi');
        // Get all homes from DB
        Home.find({bedrooms: regexBed}, function(err, allHomes){
           if(err){
               console.log(err);
           } else {
              if(allHomes.length < 1) {
                  noMatch = "No homes match that query, please try again.";
              }
              res.render("homes/index",{homes:allHomes, noMatch: noMatch});
           }
        });
    } else {
        // Get all homes from DB
        Home.find({}, function(err, allHomes){
           if(err){
               console.log(err);
           } else {
              res.render("homes/index",{homes:allHomes, noMatch: noMatch});
           }
        });
    }

}

//end of bed function

function bathroomSearch() {
  var noMatch = null;
    if(req.query.bath) {
        const regexBath = new RegExp(escapeRegex(req.query.bath), 'gi');
        // Get all homes from DB
        Home.find({bathrooms: regexBath}, function(err, allHomes){
           if(err){
               console.log(err);
           } else {
              if(allHomes.length < 1) {
                  noMatch = "No homes match that query, please try again.";
              }
              res.render("homes/index",{homes:allHomes, noMatch: noMatch});
           }
        });
    } else {
        // Get all homes from DB
        Home.find({}, function(err, allHomes){
           if(err){
               console.log(err);
           } else {
              res.render("homes/index",{homes:allHomes, noMatch: noMatch});
           }
        });
    }

}

//end of bathroom function


// For form 
function escapeRegex(text) {
    return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing the `req` or `res` variables to the other functions. The scope of the `req` and `res` parameter is only tied to the callback function in `router.get`.

You could just pass the `req` and `res` parameters to the functions you're calling:

```js
router.get("/", function(req, res){
  //function to search by city
  citySearch(req, res);

  //function to search by bedrooms
  bedroomSearch(req, res);

  //function to search by bathrooms
  bathroomSearch(req, res);
});
```

And receive those variables in each of the functions so they could make use of them:

```js
function citySearch(req, res) {
  // Rest of code...
}

function bedroomSearch(req, res) {
  // Rest of code
}

function bathroomSearch(req, res) {
  // Rest of code
}
```

Comment: The code work. But for For some odd reason the citySearch function take more priority over the other functions. If use select the city and the number of bedrooms form the menu, the search will only show them the homes from the city they picked. How do I make all the form data work together as a group? Thank you, for your help.

Comment: @vaughnwatson It's not that odd, that happens because every function has a `res.render()` statement which tells Express to send the HTML to the browser, when the code reaches a `res.render()` everything else is done. You've got to remove the `res.render` statements from the functions and return an object there and manage the three object responses in the `router.get` callback.